# Qt4: adjust which widget get focused on start

Tags: qt, qt4, window, focus

If I don't re-implement `QMainWindow::showEvent()` (which will contains a setFocus() method for that widget), is there any way to let some widget get focused first, when the window is loaded ? I use form editor of Qt4, but failed to find somewhere to configure that.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can set the [Tab Order](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/designer-tab-order.html) in Qt Designer or the Designer component in Qt Creator. The first widget in the tab order should get focus on load.

> [image: tab order]
>
> Many users expect to be able to navigate between widgets and controls
> using only the keyboard. Qt lets the user navigate between input
> widgets with the <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Shift+Tab</kbd> keyboard shortcuts. The default tab
> order is based on the order in which widgets are constructed. Although
> this order may be sufficient for many users, it is often better to
> explicitly specify the tab order to make your application easier to
> use.
>
> **Setting the Tab Order**
>
> To enter tab order editing mode, open the *Edit* menu and select *Edit
> Tab Order*. In this mode, each input widget in the form is shown with a
> number indicating its position in the tab order. So, if the user gives
> the first input widget the input focus and then presses the tab key,
> the focus will move to the second input widget, and so on.
>
> The tab order is defined by clicking on each of the numbers in the
> correct order. The first number you click will change to red,
> indicating the currently edited position in the tab order chain. The
> widget associated with the number will become the first one in the tab
> order chain. Clicking on another widget will make it the second in the
> tab order, and so on.
>
> Repeat this process until you are satisfied with the tab order in the
> form -- you do not need to click every input widget if you see that
> the remaining widgets are already in the correct order. Numbers, for
> which you already set the order, change to green, while those which
> are not clicked yet, remain blue.
>
> If you make a mistake, simply double click outside of any number or
> choose Restart from the form's context menu to start again. If you
> have many widgets on your form and would like to change the tab order
> in the middle or at the end of the tab order chain, you can edit it at
> any position. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and click the number from which you want to
> start. Alternatively, choose *Start from Here* in the context menu.

Answer (score 11):

Never used the form editor, but you could just call the widgets [setFocus method](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#setFocus) in your code after creating the main window.