# QT: How to control the cursor in MainWindow.ui

Tags: qt, qwidget, qtextedit

In Qt, I have three QTextEdit1 widgets aligned vertically in MainWindow.ui. When I run the application, the cursor always becomes active on the QTextEdit2 widget (not the first which the user must fill first). Another issue is when I press tab on the keyboard, it goes to QTextEdit3 which is ok. but when press Tab again it goes to QTextEdit5, ignoring QTextEdit4. The following explain more.

```
QTextEdit1
QTextEdit2 [the cursor is always on this QTextEdit]
QTextEdit3 [first tab]
QTextEdit4 
QTextEdit5 [second tab]
```

I want the cursor to become active on the first QTextEdit and when I press tab it goes to the next one weather it is vertically or horizontally aligned. Now it seems it jumps randomly !!

Comment: I think your question is addressed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15570156/qt-focus-changing-order

Comment: Also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11120428/qt4-adjust-which-widget-get-focused-on-start